# Need For Uniform Browser Engine

Tags: java, php, asp.net, html, css

Of course, we have been witnessing a lot of browsers differences in rendering elements, in displaying those, the support for CSS, the support for html/xhtml standards and more importantly different layout engines such as Trident, Tasman, Gecko, KHTML, WebKit and Presto which is mainly why there are differences.

I just wonder why there isn't a uniform/agreed upon or centralized layout engine so that browsers differences are put to an end or probably to keep them as minimum as possible.

Why we, the developers, are messing around with differences like idiots, correcting things for each browsers?

Until what we will remain to like like idiots in the eyes of engine makers?

Are there any future of plans of those ^joints^ to do some centralized stuff?

Here are some of the details of what I am talking about:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_web_browsers#Gecko-based_browsers

Thanks guys.

Comment: This is a very large question indeed. A lot of factors are involved. It's interesting though to see the comments and answers about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I cannot fault you for wanting to see this come about (I too would love to see a standard rendering engine across the board) you should really consider the magnitude of effort that would be involved to create a cooperative effort to accomplish this.

The web browser market has always been (and will remain) a competitive one.  As such there is little to no incentive to standardize.

For more information I would recommend that you read about [the history of the web browser](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_the_web_browser)  to understand the deep lines that would prevent such a cooperative venture.

Comment: Furthermore, suppose Apple, Microsoft, Mozilla, Google, Apple and Opera agreed tomorrow to standardise on a particular engine.  How many years until that agreed engine actually sat on 99% of user desktops?  Even if every *vendor* adopted, say, Gecko tomorrow, *consumers* wouldn't (why should they?): we'd still be working around IE6 issues in 2015.

Answer (score 0):

From a business viewpoint it doesn't make sense to have shared property, otherwise you don't have an edge on the competition.

Edit: The solution to your question would be an ideal open source world, but that cannot be the case, even in the current open source world. Somebody thinks they can do something better and they fork instead of contribute. It also comes down to things like ownership, human nature, interpersonal relationships, competitiveness, none of which are bad, but those things always throw monkey wrenches into an ideal world.

Comment: the can still do the business by improving their browsers/ adding more features to it?

Comment: if the business is the main thing, they should probably provide their own implementation of everything html, xthml, css with a great features. this way the one who provides better html, xhtml, css support and options will be winner.

Comment: but they have uniformity on html, xhtml, css, same should be on layout engines i think.

Comment: There should be uniformity on the *results*, sure.  But suppose, say, Opera comes up with a way to process CSS faster.  Today, they can ship it and promote it as a reason to use Opera.  In your world, they'd have to negotiate with the One True Layout Engine committee to get their changes adopted (so they can't ship it until it's folded into the OTLE), and then everybody would get it (so they don't benefit from their R&D efforts, because Microsoft and Mozilla get the same feature at the same time).  What's in it for them?